# protoc generated grpc files and gateway files end up in different paths?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

I'm a bit baffled about this. File structure:

```
/Project
generate.sh
  gateway/
      cmd/
          main.go
      pkg/
          gatewaypb/
      proto/ 
         service.proto
```

My `generate.sh` appears as such:

```
set -e

module="github.com/my-org/grpc-project"
// Find all dirs with .proto files in them
for proto in */proto; do

    dir=$(echo "$proto"|cut -d"/" -f1)
    echo "regenerating generated protobuf code for ${proto}"
    protoc --proto_path .\
           --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=module=${module}\
           --go_out=. --go_opt=module=${module}\
           "${proto}"/*.proto
    echo "creating reverse proxy protobuf code for ${proto}"

    protoc -I . --grpc-gateway_out=.\
     --grpc-gateway_opt logtostderr=true \
     --grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative \
     "${proto}"/*.proto
done
```

Correctly enough, the first `protoc` does as intended, while the second one does not. They output files in different paths when they are supposed to be in the same.

After running `generate.sh`, I am left with:

```
/Project
generate.sh
  Service/
      cmd/
          main.go
      pkg/
          gatewaypb/
              *gateway.pb.go
              *gateway._grpc.pb.go
      proto/ 
         *gateway.pb.gw.go
         service.proto
```

Why does the generated gateway file end up in the `proto/` directory?

What do I need to give as a value to `grpc-gateway-out` for it to end up in `/pkg/gatewaypb` as the other generated grpc files?

My `service.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package gateway.api.v1;
option go_package = "github.com/my-org/grpc-project/gateway/pkg/gatewaypb";

import "google/api/annotations.proto";

message StringMessage {
  string value = 1;
}

service YourService {
      rpc Echo(StringMessage) returns (StringMessage) {
          option (google.api.http) = {
              post: "/v1/example/echo"
              body: "*"
            };
      }
}
```

Comment: Try `--grpc-gateway_opt module=${module}` (replacing `--grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative`). Doing this should mean the same logic is used as the other plugins (more info in [this issue](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/pull/1756#issuecomment-709580063)).

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! Feel welcome to put in an answer with a reasoning and I'll make sure to accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments you were using the module option (`--go_opt=module=${module}` & `--go-grpc_opt=module=${module}`) when generating the protobuf & gRPC files. The option you were using when generating the gateway files (`--grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative`) uses a different algorithm to work out where to store the files; the fix being to use the module option - `--grpc-gateway_opt module=${module}`.

Here is what [the docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated) have to say about the three options (these specific options are for protobuf generation; the other generators have the same functionality but replace `go_` with `go-grpc_`/`grpc-gateway_`):

- By default, the output file is placed in a directory named after the Go package's import path. For example, a file protos/foo.proto with the above go_package option results in a file named example.com/foo/bar/foo.pb.go.
- If the --go_opt=module=$PREFIX flag is given to protoc, the specified directory prefix is removed from the output filename. For example, a file protos/foo.proto with the go_package option "example.com/foo/bar" and the flag --go_opt=module=example.com/foo results in a file named bar/foo.pb.go.
- If the --go_opt=paths=source_relative flag is given to protoc, the output file is placed in the same relative directory as the input file. For example, the file protos/foo.proto results in a file named protos/foo.pb.go.